# iOS - can't write to file on simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, cocoa-touch, plist

I'n trying to save a simple .plist file to my `documentsDirectory`. I have followed Facebooks documentation for saving tokens and I have implemented the following methods:

```
static NSString* kFilename = @"TokenInfo.plist";

[...]

- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _tokenFilePath = [self filePath];
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSString *)filePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths lastObject];

    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kFilename];
}

- (void)writeData:(NSDictionary *)data {

    NSLog(@"File = %@ and Data = %@", self.tokenFilePath, data);

    BOOL success = [data writeToFile:self.tokenFilePath atomically:YES];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Error writing to file");
    }
}
```

I currently get `NSLog(@"Error writing to file");` printed very time. Any ideas on why that is?

Comment: Use `writeToFile:options:error:` and log the error. That is why they have `NSError`. Also you show `filePath` but use `self.tokenFilePath`.

Comment: You are attempting to write to the documentation directory, not the documents directory. You probably want `NSDocumentDirectory`, not `NSDocumentationDirectory`.

Comment: What is the output of that first `NSLog` statement in `writeData`? Are you certain the `tokenFilePath` is valid?

Comment: @Aaron has the correct answer! Make is an answer.

Comment: @Aaron Oh, good catch. Changing to `NSDocumentDirectory` made it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `NSDocumentDirectory` not `NSDocumentationDirectory`. Code completion in Xcode offers the documentation directory before the document directory enum. This is super easy to miss.

Answer (score 0):

Also check to Documents directory exist, it's safe to create it

Add this snippet to  `- (NSString *)filePath` method before `return`

```
NSFileManager * fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError * err;
[fm createDirectoryAtPath: documentsDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&err];
if (err)
{
    NSLog(@"%@ ", err.localizedDescription);
}
```

Comment: At least on the simulator there is no need for this, even if the Documents directory is missing it is automatically created. `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)` creates it. Apple did the right thing. But nice guess.

Comment: Got ut to work using this. But Aaron provided the correct answer in the comment above. I had accidentally written `NSDocumentationDirectory`.

Comment: Actually this is rather dangerous, it will eliminate the error but will **not** write to the expected/correct directory potentially causing other problems later.

Comment: @Zaph yes, you are right, but check that path exists before writing also not bad idea,  not so?